# How to Convert String contains Unicode Shortcut into TRUE Unicode character in R?

Tags: r, unicode

I Have this String contains shortcut of specific characters of emoji representation:

```
x <- "\\U0001F48C"
```

How to convert it to True Unicode (Using Concatenation), as equivalent as:

```
y <- "\U0001F48C"
```

cat is a handy tool to inspect this Unicode (at least this is what I knew)

```
cat(y)
```

But I will want to build some function that pass a certain last unique encoding, for example in this case

```
converter <- function(last_unicode_label="1F48C"){
  #convert as equivalent as y
}
```

list of encoding can be found here: https://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various ways to do this. Perhaps the easiest is to convert the hexadecimal part of your string to an integer and use `intToUtf8` from base R:

```
mystr <- c("\\U0001F48C", "\\U0001F48D")
mystr
#> [1] "\\U0001F48C" "\\U0001F48D"

mystr <- unlist(lapply(as.list(gsub("\\\\U", "0x", mystr)), intToUtf8))
mystr
#> [1] "\U0001f48c" "\U0001f48d"
```

Which is probably best replaced by a little utility function:

```
unescape <- function(x) unlist(lapply(as.list(gsub("\\\\U", "0x", x)), intToUtf8))
```

Comment: I see, so this is one of the purpose to use Hexadecimal Codes.. Thanks :)